# How to set php 8.0 as default version in ubuntu server

Tags: php, php7

For some reason, i have to install PHP 7.4 and PHP 8.0 in the same ubuntu server. By default when i install php 7.4, it shows it is the default version when use the command `php -v`.

But i want to run composer using PHP 8.0 now to install one of my application in the server. Server cant find any php version now, so i cant install my application using composer.

**How did i install PHP 8.0**

I have used `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` this repository to install latest version of 8.0 in the server, I can make it work with caddy server and even site is running fine in my testing environment. `https://caddyt.tamilchatz.com` << you can check out this URL to make sure my 8.0 is running fine in server.

Anyway i have removed PHP 7.4 from server to make sure does it help me to set 8.0 as default one, but no i can't get it to work.

```
php --version
```

[Screen Shot Image of php version result from the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUyFX.png)

Help me out to set PHP 8.0 as default version in server now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You will likely need to do two things:

1. Set the alternative version to your 8.0 installation:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.0
   ```
2. Confirm you have the CLI (Command Line Interface) package installed:

   ```
   sudo apt install php8.0-cli
   ```

From here you should be good to go.